# Arguments to path.join must be strings when installing Bower on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, bower, bower-install

I am experiencing the following error when attempting to install Bower on Mac OSX Mavericks.

```
Craig-R-Mortons-MacBook:crmpicco crmpicco$ node_modules/bower/bin/bower cache clean
Craig-R-Mortons-MacBook:crmpicco crmpicco$ node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.2.9
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.2.9
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.2.9
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.2.9
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.9
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.9
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2.7
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2.7
bower not-cached    git://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#~1.5.2
bower resolve       git://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#~1.5.2
bower error         Arguments to path.join must be strings

Stack trace:
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at Object.posix.join (path.js:471:13)
    at GitHubResolver._checkout (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/lib/core/resolvers/GitHubResolver.js:54:21)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/lib/core/resolvers/GitResolver.js:69:21
    at _fulfilled (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:74:17)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:109:18)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Logger.emit (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/install.js:27:16
    at _rejected (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crmpicco/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.6
Node version: 0.12.0
OS: Darwin 14.1.0 x64
```

I came across [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1403), however updating to Bower 1.3.6 has no effect for me - even after doing a `bower cache clean` and `npm cache clean`.

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "bower",
  "version": "1.3.6",
  "description": "The browser package manager.",
  "author": {
    "name": "Twitter"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/bower/bower.git"
  },
  "main": "lib",
  "homepage": "http://bower.io",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "abbrev": "~1.0.4",
    "archy": "0.0.2",
    "bower-config": "~0.5.0",
    "bower-endpoint-parser": "~0.2.0",
    "bower-json": "~0.4.0",
    "bower-logger": "~0.2.1",
    "bower-registry-client": "~0.1.4",
    "cardinal": "~0.4.0",
    "chalk": "~0.2.0",
    "chmodr": "~0.1.0",
    "decompress-zip": "~0.0.3",
    "fstream": "~0.1.22",
    "fstream-ignore": "~0.0.6",
    "glob": "~3.2.1",
    "graceful-fs": "~2.0.0",
    "handlebars": "~1.0.11",
    "inquirer": "~0.3.0",
    "junk": "~0.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "~0.3.5",
    "mout": "~0.7.0",
    "nopt": "~2.1.1",
    "lru-cache": "~2.3.0",
    "open": "~0.0.3",
    "osenv": "0.0.3",
    "promptly": "~0.2.0",
    "q": "~0.9.2",
    "request": "~2.27.0",
    "request-progress": "~0.3.0",
    "retry": "~0.6.0",
    "rimraf": "~2.2.0",
    "semver": "~2.1.0",
    "stringify-object": "~0.1.4",
    "sudo-block": "~0.2.0",
    "tar": "~0.1.17",
    "tmp": "~0.0.20",
    "update-notifier": "~0.1.3",
    "which": "~1.0.5",
    "p-throttler": "~0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tmp": "0.0.23",
    "bower": "1.3.6",
    "expect.js": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-simple-mocha": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-exec": "~0.4.2",
    "mocha": "~1.12.0",
    "nock": "~0.22.0",
    "istanbul": "~0.1.42",
    "proxyquire": "~0.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "bin": {
    "bower": "bin/bower"
  },
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/bower/bower/issues"
  },
  "_id": "bower@1.2.8",
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "f63c0804a267d5ffaf2fd3fd488367e73dce202f",
    "tarball": "http://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.2.8.tgz"
  },
  "_from": "bower@>=1.2.8 <1.3.0",
  "_npmVersion": "1.3.14",
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "wibblymat",
    "email": "mat@wibbly.org.uk"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "fat",
      "email": "jacobthornton@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "satazor",
      "email": "andremiguelcruz@msn.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "wibblymat",
      "email": "mat@wibbly.org.uk"
    },
    {
      "name": "paulirish",
      "email": "paul.irish@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "directories": {},
  "_shasum": "f63c0804a267d5ffaf2fd3fd488367e73dce202f",
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.2.8.tgz"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem today by updating bower to the latest version.  As of today, the current version is 1.4.1.  You can check the current version by looking in the the [package.json](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/package.json) on github.

To do update bower, I ran the following command:

```
npm install -g bower
```

I think this error was caused because of the following lines that are in my .gitconfig file.  This line is there because I am trying to work around being in a corporate environment with proxy servers.

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```